# cant import flask-wtf after install

Tags: flask

I have been looking around for an answer to this question, but everywhere I see the advice of running a `pip install flask-wtf` in the virtual environment. The requirements have already been satisfied in mine, but for some reason I am getting a missing module error. I am working on a school project building a website using `flask` and would really appreciate the help. My import is:

```
from flask_wtf import Form`
```

When I try to run the install command I get a message that says the requirement is already satisfied, as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymTyK.png).

Comment: Is your virtual environment activated when you run the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot, your `flask-wtf` and friends are installed outside virtualenvs, in the system site-packages directory.

It'd be a good idea to uninstall those from the global site-packages directory (`python3 -m pip uninstall flask-wtf wtforms flask jinja2 click werkzeug markupsafe itsdangerous`), create and activate a virtualenv (`python3 -m venv my_venv` and `./my_venv/bin/activate`), then reinstall the dependencies within the virtualenv.